# Chromedriver not starting in docker

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver

Im trying to run chromedriver insider docker. But Im getting bind error. There are no process running in port 9515. Can someone please tell me what went wrong

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7) on port 9515
    Only local connections are allowed.
    [1531829365.521][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error, errno=99: Cannot assign requested address (99)
    [1531829365.521][INFO]: listen on IPv6 failed with error ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Environment

```
 Docker version       : 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
 ChromeDriver version : 2.40.565383
 BaseImage            : debian:jessie
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems we need enable ipv6 in docker. Adding this to the docker configuration solved the issue for me.

```
{ "ipv6" : true }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker compose, the enable_ipv6 option must be set, and you must use a version 2.x Compose file. IPv6 options do not currently work in swarm mode i.e. version 3.x Compose file.